# AWK for extracting numeric data

Tags: awk, grep

I have an output Residuals file from a CFD simulation. The file starts with text and then the numeric values appear. The numeric data is a collection of iterations and values of different variable at each iteration. But in between each row of iterations i have text. I want to read only the numeric values. Again in the end, after the last iteration i have some text which i do not want. How can i acheive this using "grep" or "awk" ?

```
Conjugate-Gradient solver did not converge !
Iteration     Continuity     X-momentum     Y-momentum     Z-momentum         Energy            Tke            Sdr  Intermittency Heat Transfer 1 (W)    Pinlet (Pa)   T_outlet (K) twallFroide (K) surf_avg_q_crit (/s^2) Maximum tempfroide (K) Surface Average Helicity (/s) 
             1   1.851301e-09   1.213569e-07   2.692437e-09   4.273490e-10   1.888124e-03   3.166891e-07   5.527057e-06   1.418467e-23       -9.974981e+00   2.505598e+03   2.900000e+02    4.000053e+02          -1.627486e+06           4.000053e+02                  9.216386e+03 

 Conjugate-Gradient solver did not converge !
             2   1.506520e-09   6.493389e-08   1.170308e-08   1.013586e-08   3.910613e-04   1.808261e-08   1.438014e+00   8.318085e-08       -9.193516e+00   3.435342e+03   2.899868e+02    4.000056e+02          -3.203329e+05           4.000056e+02                  1.100795e+04 

 Conjugate-Gradient solver did not converge !
             3   1.525969e-09   3.735938e-08   6.075371e-09   5.903247e-09   1.463379e-04   1.838257e-08   8.408794e-01   4.541057e-08       -5.458547e+00   3.763758e+03   2.899876e+02    4.000063e+02          -8.800786e+04           4.000063e+02                  1.215424e+04 
Iteration     Continuity     X-momentum     Y-momentum     Z-momentum         Energy            Tke            Sdr  Intermittency Heat Transfer 1 (W)    Pinlet (Pa)   T_outlet (K) twallFroide (K) surf_avg_q_crit (/s^2) Maximum tempfroide (K) Surface Average Helicity (/s) 
            11   3.111921e-10   6.967732e-09   1.939856e-09   1.489035e-09   3.637339e-05   1.190901e-08   1.233295e-03   1.514342e-08       -3.424275e-01  -2.047953e+02   2.900011e+02    3.904010e+02          -5.810358e+05           3.905252e+02                  1.336589e+04 

 Conjugate-Gradient solver did not converge !
            12   2.750237e-10   6.604475e-09   1.869473e-09   1.402315e-09   2.681946e-05   1.108801e-08   5.955147e-04   2.128098e-08       -5.063177e-01   3.204832e+01   2.899994e+02    3.851287e+02          -6.980901e+05           3.853471e+02                  1.349346e+04 

          1486   1.772877e-10   1.146380e-08   5.247957e-09   2.874375e-09   2.170361e-04   2.508185e-09   6.915671e-05   1.255282e-08        4.900716e+00   1.318869e+02   2.957356e+02    3.059026e+02          -2.345214e+06           3.087469e+02                  1.762329e+04 
          1487   1.794266e-10   1.145211e-08   5.258921e-09   2.874134e-09   1.135887e-04   2.508012e-09   6.529728e-05   1.261970e-08        4.907054e+00   1.317913e+02   2.957361e+02    3.059022e+02          -2.518939e+06           3.087460e+02                  1.762613e+04 
Temperature corrections limited on 7 cells in glue1
Temperature corrections limited on 1 cells in glue2
```

i have copied some data as an example. i Do not want to save anything before iteration 1, any text in between and any text after my last iteration. Please suggest

thanks

Bineet

Comment: Could you please clean up your post a bit? What is the exact input and what is the desired output?

Comment: @Bineet, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers on what to do if you get answers that solve your issues

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what your expected output is, but if you want to extract only rows that start with a numeric value (after a possible whitespace), `grep` will do just fine.

For your sample input:

```
$ grep -P '^\s*\d+' sim
             1   1.851301e-09   1.213569e-07   2.692437e-09   4.273490e-10   1.888124e-03   3.166891e-07   5.527057e-06   1.418467e-23       -9.974981e+00   2.505598e+03   2.900000e+02    4.000053e+02          -1.627486e+06           4.000053e+02                  9.216386e+03 
             2   1.506520e-09   6.493389e-08   1.170308e-08   1.013586e-08   3.910613e-04   1.808261e-08   1.438014e+00   8.318085e-08       -9.193516e+00   3.435342e+03   2.899868e+02    4.000056e+02          -3.203329e+05           4.000056e+02                  1.100795e+04 
             3   1.525969e-09   3.735938e-08   6.075371e-09   5.903247e-09   1.463379e-04   1.838257e-08   8.408794e-01   4.541057e-08       -5.458547e+00   3.763758e+03   2.899876e+02    4.000063e+02          -8.800786e+04           4.000063e+02                  1.215424e+04 
            11   3.111921e-10   6.967732e-09   1.939856e-09   1.489035e-09   3.637339e-05   1.190901e-08   1.233295e-03   1.514342e-08       -3.424275e-01  -2.047953e+02   2.900011e+02    3.904010e+02          -5.810358e+05           3.905252e+02                  1.336589e+04 
            12   2.750237e-10   6.604475e-09   1.869473e-09   1.402315e-09   2.681946e-05   1.108801e-08   5.955147e-04   2.128098e-08       -5.063177e-01   3.204832e+01   2.899994e+02    3.851287e+02          -6.980901e+05           3.853471e+02                  1.349346e+04 
          1486   1.772877e-10   1.146380e-08   5.247957e-09   2.874375e-09   2.170361e-04   2.508185e-09   6.915671e-05   1.255282e-08        4.900716e+00   1.318869e+02   2.957356e+02    3.059026e+02          -2.345214e+06           3.087469e+02                  1.762329e+04 
          1487   1.794266e-10   1.145211e-08   5.258921e-09   2.874134e-09   1.135887e-04   2.508012e-09   6.529728e-05   1.261970e-08        4.907054e+00   1.317913e+02   2.957361e+02    3.059022e+02          -2.518939e+06           3.087460e+02                  1.762613e+04
```

(`-P` activates the PCRE mode, `^` anchors the match to line beginning, `\s*` allows for zero or more whitespace characters that can precede at least one digit `\d+`.)

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Comment: @Bineet, if you feel one of the answers is the best solution to your problem, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that answer. It helps the community, since it marks the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '$1~/^[0-9]+/' file
```

The output:

```
     1   1.851301e-09   1.213569e-07   2.692437e-09   4.273490e-10   1.888124e-03   3.166891e-07   5.527057e-06   1.418467e-23       -9.974981e+00   2.505598e+03   2.900000e+02    4.000053e+02          -1.627486e+06           4.000053e+02                  9.216386e+03 
     2   1.506520e-09   6.493389e-08   1.170308e-08   1.013586e-08   3.910613e-04   1.808261e-08   1.438014e+00   8.318085e-08       -9.193516e+00   3.435342e+03   2.899868e+02    4.000056e+02          -3.203329e+05           4.000056e+02                  1.100795e+04 
     3   1.525969e-09   3.735938e-08   6.075371e-09   5.903247e-09   1.463379e-04   1.838257e-08   8.408794e-01   4.541057e-08       -5.458547e+00   3.763758e+03   2.899876e+02    4.000063e+02          -8.800786e+04           4.000063e+02                  1.215424e+04 
    11   3.111921e-10   6.967732e-09   1.939856e-09   1.489035e-09   3.637339e-05   1.190901e-08   1.233295e-03   1.514342e-08       -3.424275e-01  -2.047953e+02   2.900011e+02    3.904010e+02          -5.810358e+05           3.905252e+02                  1.336589e+04 
    12   2.750237e-10   6.604475e-09   1.869473e-09   1.402315e-09   2.681946e-05   1.108801e-08   5.955147e-04   2.128098e-08       -5.063177e-01   3.204832e+01   2.899994e+02    3.851287e+02          -6.980901e+05           3.853471e+02                  1.349346e+04 
  1486   1.772877e-10   1.146380e-08   5.247957e-09   2.874375e-09   2.170361e-04   2.508185e-09   6.915671e-05   1.255282e-08        4.900716e+00   1.318869e+02   2.957356e+02    3.059026e+02          -2.345214e+06           3.087469e+02                  1.762329e+04 
  1487   1.794266e-10   1.145211e-08   5.258921e-09   2.874134e-09   1.135887e-04   2.508012e-09   6.529728e-05   1.261970e-08        4.907054e+00   1.317913e+02   2.957361e+02    3.059022e+02          -2.518939e+06           3.087460e+02                  1.762613e+04
```

Comment: Works perfectly .. Thanks